# Django checks form validity multiple times

Tags: python, django, validation, recaptcha

I am working on an old Django 1.8 application and adding ReCaptchas to contact forms.

Since this Django version is not supported by current Captcha modules I am rolling my own functionality which is pretty straightforward thanks to Googles good documentation.

The problem I am having is with form validation.
I have a class based form in which I am implementing my own `clean` method. In the `clean` method I am handling the request/response to Googles ReCaptcha Service.

This is all well and good. When submitting the form, the `post` method in my `views.py` calls `is_valid()` on the form which calls the `clean` method of the form.
I get a successful response from Google and move on to render the view.
But then, for some reason, the forms validity is checked once again but then I get a failure from Googles ReCaptcha service because it is a duplicate request.
I then get of cause a `ValidationError` and get sent back to the form.

I stepped through the code with `pdb` and found that my `clean` methods get called again when `response.render()` gets called in `../django/core/handlers/base.py(164)get_response()`.

Why does Django check the forms validity twice?
Can I circumvent it?
If not, how do I at least not check for the Captchas correctness multiple times?

```py
views.py:

...

class DirectoryDetailView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    template_name = 'directory/supplierentry_detail.html'

    def get_render_context(self, **kwargs):
        sensors = Sensor.objects.frontend().filter(language=get_language()).filter(supplier_id=self.entry.supplier.id)
        devices = Device.objects.frontend().filter(sensors__in=sensors)

        context = {
            'entry': self.entry,
            'object': self.entry,
            'sensors': sensors.order_by('-created')[:12],
            'devices': devices,
            'supplier_news': self.entry.supplier_news.frontend().filter(language=get_language()).order_by('-published'),
            'supplier_products_id': self.entry.supplier.id,
        }
        return context

    def render_to_response(self, context=None, **response_kwargs):
        render_context = self.get_render_context()
        if context:
            render_context.update(context)
        return super(DirectoryDetailView, self).render_to_response(render_context, **response_kwargs)


class DirectoryEnquiryView(DirectoryEnquiryFormMixin, DirectoryDetailView):
    template_name = 'directory/supplierentry_detail_contact.html'


    def get_render_context(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DirectoryEnquiryView, self).get_render_context(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'form': self.get_form(entry=self.entry, request=self.request),
        })
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        from ..enquiry_data.utils import set_enquiry_data
        self.parse_query()
        context = self.get_render_context()
        form = context['form']
        if form.is_valid():
            self.send_email(form)
            messages.info(request, _(u'Your message was sent.'))
            return set_enquiry_data(self.render_to_response(), request, form)
        else:
            return self.render_to_response()

...
```

```py
forms.py:

...

class EntryEnquiryForm(forms.Form):
    ... some attributes...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.entry = kwargs.pop('entry', None)
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(EntryEnquiryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_message(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data.get('message')
        if message:
            pattern = re.compile('(\[url=|\[link=|<a[^>]+href=)')
            if pattern.search(message):
                self._errors['message'] = [_(u'We think your message is spam.')]
        return message

    def clean(self):
        # begin reCAPTCHA validation
        recaptcha_response = self.request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        data = {
            'secret':  'some_secret',
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }
        r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
        result = r.json()
        # end reCAPTCHA validation
        if result['success']:
            return
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _(u'Captcha validation not successful.'),
                code='invalid')
```

```py
utils.py:

def generate_enquiry_data(request, form, extend_existing=True):
    if extend_existing:
        data = get_enquiry_data(request)
    else:
        data = {}
    for f in ('name', 'email', 'telefon', 'company', 'cc_self'):
        if f in form.cleaned_data:
            data[f] = form.cleaned_data[f]
    return signing.dumps(data, salt=SALT, compress=True)


def get_enquiry_data(request):
    if COOKIE_NAME in request.COOKIES:
        try:
            return signing.loads(request.COOKIES[COOKIE_NAME], salt=SALT)
        except signing.BadSignature:
            pass # just ignore invalid data
    return {}


def set_enquiry_data(response, request, form, extend_existing=True):
    enquiry_data = generate_enquiry_data(request, form, extend_existing=extend_existing)
    response.set_cookie(COOKIE_NAME, value=enquiry_data, expires=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=180), httponly=True)
    return response
```

Comment: You should show the code of your form and view.

Comment: what you're saying is not possible, unless you instantiate the form again (rendering would probably call `form.errors` on the new form). But it's not clear what `DirectoryDetailView` is. Because a generic `DetailView` requires a `context` argument when calling `self.render_to_response()` so apparently you've modified it otherwise it would crash. Show us your `render_to_response()` method and your `set_enquiry_data` function.

Comment: @dirkgroten I added the methods above. You are right. The form gets instantiated a second time. It happens when `self.get_render_context()` gets called in `render_to response()`. The `context.update(...)` does the instatiation and when the above described `response = response.render()` gets called, the form gets validated a second time.

Comment: I would add that I inherited the application and don't yet understand fully what the previous dev team did in lots of places.

Comment: I would rewrite these classes to only override `get_context_data` and not `render_to_response` )and remove the `get_render_context` method. Go to ccbv.co.uk  to see how View and TemplateResponseMixin work. The context is built once and only updated if needed before passing it to `render_to_response`.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks for these pointers. I will investigate further.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you so much. With your pointers I was able to rewrite the class in a proper way. And with the rewrite the form only gets instantiated once.